# Mongodb schema, keeping a count field or counting documents from separate collection

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I am facing a dilemma in my MongoDB schema design.

The site I am working on has support for comments. These comments have their own schema.

```
comment=
{
   _id: objectId,
   text: "example",
   author: authorObjectId,
   postId: objectId
}
```

Comments can be posted in Posts. Posts have their own schema also.

```
post=
{
   _id: objectId,
   title: "example",
   author: authorObjectId
}
```

I need to add a commentCount field to the posts when I return them to the frontend.

From my understanding, there are 2 ways to go about this.

1. Define a `commentCount` in postSchema, and increment/decrement it every time I add/remove a comment using `$inc`
2. Use aggregation, (project + find) when querying posts and count the comments from the comment collection.

Which solution is better for performance? Which one is the best? I don't have many users right now but I would want to take the right approach from the beginning. Because this solution will be used in many other schemas (upvotes, karma, etc.).

Also! I have tried implementing the aggregation and I couldn't come up with a query that would be able to count documents from comments collection and use the result in the `project` stage.